# Some the objects turn black Problem with Render on Cycles after press F12

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

When I press  <kbd>F12</kbd> all sushi model appears on black. Only when render on Cycles, but on EEVEE shows totally normal.

[image]

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iu2PiEmHyw0GZcp6gBHszmoclj3NDCRp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and making it more understandable, it is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your sushi, go in *Edit* mode, select the mesh with <kbd>L</kbd>, and move it, you'll see that you have a mesh overlapping (and even several). In Cycles if you have overlapping faces it won't render correctly (it's called *Z fighting*). To fix it select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

[image]

Comment: Really Thanks, you asking me again, really thanks ♥ Solved